# How can I improve this Entity Framework LINQ query

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following EF query that is taking about 20 seconds to return ~100k rows.  If I remove the "Addresses" and "Contacts" subqueries (if that's what you call them) in the select statement it takes about 2 seconds to return.  Is there a more efficient way to create the Employee object with the lists of addresses and contacts associated with an employee?

```
            return await (from account in _databaseContext.Accounts
                join client in _databaseContext.Clients on account.AddressClientID equals client.ClientId
                      where client.EffectiveTo == null
                      && client.ClientType.Equals("PERSON")
                      && account.EffectiveTo == null
                      && account.Status.Equals("INFORCE")
                select new Employee
                {
                    Id = account.AccountId,
                    ClientId = client.ClientId,
                    FirstName = client.GivenNames,
                    LastName = client.Surname,
                    Gender = client.Gender,
                    Addresses = client.ClientAddresses.Where(x => x.EffectiveTo == null)
                        .Select(x => AddressFactory.Create(x)).ToList(),
                    Contacts = client.ClientContacts.Where(x => x.EffectiveTo == null && (x.ContactType == "EMAIL" || x.ContactType == "MOBILE"))
                        .OrderBy(y => y.EffectiveFrom)
                        .Select(z => ContactFactory.Create<Employee>(client, z)).ToList(),
                    DateOfBirth = client.DateOfBirth
                }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: You should use navigation-properties and `.Include` instead of `join`.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you have two `EffectiveTo` properties/columns? That looks like a denormalization to me...

Comment: @Dai This is a 3rd party db I'm querying so I have no control over database design unfortunately.  Should have stated that in the original post.

Comment: Do you have an example using navigation-properties?  I'm not overly experienced with EFCore.

Comment: Use `AsSplitQuery()` it will reduce count of returned records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would almost certainly be client-side evaluation at work inside the `Select` with the use of these Factory methods. Instead, change it to work explicitly to populate the desired models, and ideally define simplified view models or DTOs to represent the structure you need, with just the columns you need, which can improve indexing options/use and reduce the amount of data and such being composed.

I.e. manually compose the objects rather than using factory methods. EF cannot translate a call to `XFactory.Create()` into SQL so it will end up potentially fetching a lot of extra data into memory to pass into these factory calls. Instead, use `Select` to create instances of the classes manually. AFAIK those classes should have a default constructor and setters that EF can access.

Also consider why you might need to return 100k rows. If this is information a user is viewing, consider employing server-side pagination to load paged data so that maybe only 100 or so rows are fetched at a time.

Edit: Regarding navigation properties, these are references from one entity to related ones using one-to-many, one-to-one, or many-to-many relationships. Your entities may already have these set up, for instance your classes already likely have them, as I can see client contains a ClientAddresses, so check if Account has a Client. In this case the query can be re-written as:

```
var accounts = await _databaseContext.Accounts
   .Where(a => a.Client.EffectiveTo == null
                  && a.Client.ClientType.Equals("PERSON")
                  && a.EffectiveTo == null
                  && a.Status.Equals("INFORCE"))
   .Select(a => new Employee
   {
       Id = a.AccountId,
       ClientId = a.Client.ClientId,
       FirstName = a.Client.GivenNames,
       LastName = a.Client.Surname,
       Gender = a.client.Gender,
       Addresses = a.Client.ClientAddresses
           .Where(ca => ca.EffectiveTo == null)
           .Select(ca => new Address { /* populate from client address */ }).ToList(),
       Contacts = a.Client.ClientContacts
           .Where(c => c.EffectiveTo == null && (c.ContactType == "EMAIL" || c.ContactType == "MOBILE"))
           .OrderBy(c => c.EffectiveFrom)
           .Select(c => new Contact { /* ... */ }).ToList(),
       DateOfBirth = a.Client.DateOfBirth
   }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Steve.  I'll try refactoring the factory methods as you suggest.  Unfortunately all the rows are needed as this is part of a batch operation that validates new clients (potentially hundreds at a time) to ensure they don't already exist.  Checking each new client one by one is not an option either.  I have tried pulling back Addresses and Contacts as separate result sets but am struggling to combine into a single Employee object.  I think I'll keep working on that approach though.

Comment: You might have some luck separating the queries. Normally when loading entities and relations you can use `.AsSplitQuery()` to tell EF to use sub-queries rather than joins for loading the related entities. You can manually do the same by breaking out the addresses and contacts so long as these loaded objects contain an AccountId to reference back to each relevant account.  I updated the answer above to include an example using navigation properties rather than an explicit join, to check if you have a similar relationship already set up.

Comment: Thanks Steve, you were right about the factory classes.  Removing those and explicitly creating the objects gave me a 25% improvement on the original query.  Adding in your navigation changes above added another ~5% and AsSplitQuery ~5%.  So the query has gone from ~20secs to ~12secs.  Appreciate all your help.